how to get chrome devtools request initiator call stack?
Can I get the stack through code?

I try to use chrome-remote-interface to get stack, but i find params.initiator.stack?.parent is always null.
const CDP = require("chrome-remote-interface");

(async function () {
  let client;
  try {
    client = await CDP();

    const { Page, Network } = client;

    await Promise.all([Page.enable(), Network.enable()]);

    Network.requestWillBeSent((params) => {
      console.log("Request URL:", params.request.url);
      console.log("Request Stack Trace:", params.initiator.stack?.parent);
    });

    await Page.navigate({
      url: "xxxxx",
    });
  } catch (err) {
    console.error(err);
  }
})();



It's callFrames not parent.

callFrames only has the most recent call stack,but I want to get all the call stacks.

Devtools uses both callFrames and parent, so maybe you somehow encountered a bug in Chrome.

By default collecting async stack trace is disabled. First you need to enable Debugger domain, then set setAsyncCallStackDepth to a non-zero value.
